# Why has /var/run been migrated to /run?

Tags: filesystem

From the [technical overview of Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneiricOcelot/TechnicalOverview#Upgrades):

> Ubuntu 11.10 has migrated away from `/var/run`, `/var/lock` and `/dev/shm` and now uses `/run`, `/run/lock` and `/run/shm` instead (respectively).

- I hardcode these paths in my applications, why is this change made to Oneiric?
- What can I do to make my applications backwards- and forward-compatible? Is there a better way other than checking first for the existence of `/run`, and then `/var/run`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The intent is to reduce the number of `tmpfs` file systems.  On 11.04, there are separate `tmpfs` file systems at `/var/lock`, `/var/run` and `/dev/shm`.  If these directories were all under a single parent directory, then only a single `tmpfs` would be needed.  It also provides an obvious location for further runtime state data that shouldn't persist over reboots.

Unless your application depends on canonical paths of files, your application should run without modification since the old locations will be symlinked to the new ones.  The AppArmor policies are one case that does depend on the real path names, which is why it was mentioned specifically.

The following links should help explain the rationale:

- http://lists.fedoraproject.org/pipermail/devel/2011-March/150031.html
- https://bugs.linuxfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=718
- https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/fhs-discuss/2011-May/000061.html
- http://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/RunDirectory

Answer (score 39):

1. `/run` is a new cross-distribution tmpfs location for the storage of transient state files—that is, files containing run-time information that may or may not need to be written early in the boot process and which does not require preserving across reboots.

   Making the `/run` directory available brings us a step closer to the point where it is possible to use the system normally with the root filesystem mounted read-only, without requiring any clunky workarounds such as `aufs/unionfs` overlays.

   `/run` replaces several existing locations described in the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard:

   - `/var/run` → `/run`
   - `/var/lock` → `/run/lock`
   - `/dev/shm` → `/run/shm` [currently only Debian plans to do this]
   - `/tmp` → `/run/tmp` [optional; currently only Debian plans to offer this]
   - `/run` also replaces some other locations that have been used for transient files:
   - `/lib/init/rw` → `/run`
   - `/dev/.*` → `/run/*`
   - `/dev/shm/*` → `/run/*`
   - writable files under `/etc` → `/run/*`

   (so you probably can expect these to move aswell).

   Source:[debian release goals](http://wiki.debian.org/ReleaseGoals/RunDirectory)
2. I would advice on creating a part in your software where you set these directories in variables, change your code to use these variables and then alter the variables based on the system it is used on (but I bet you knew that already).

Comment: What do you mean writable files under `/etc`. Those must all persist past reboot, right? That's just generic conf files.

Comment: Oh I see. Three files under `/etc`, `/etc/lvm/cache/` `/etc/mtab` `/etc/network/run/ifstate` and soon `/etc/adjtime`. I suppose it was bad for them to be in `/etc` to begin with.

Answer (score 6):

From what I have read, this was the original explanation given as to why /run was introduced. http://lwn.net/Articles/436012/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

You should not hardcode any of these `/run` paths!

- Use `/var/run`, because a symlink will be in place to `/run` if applicable
- `/var/lock` is the same as above
- Don't hardcode `/dev/shm` ever, always use `shm_open` etc (the posix API)

Answer (score 3):

Note: since /run introduction, small configurations might get troubles. My Ubuntu server is 256Mo RAM and /run is by default set to 49Mo.
At startup, it fills the filesystem until fullness.
Making changes in fstab does not operate to inscrease tempfs /run size. Neither does others procedures I found on gg.
I found the solution to add in init script : `/etc/rc.local` the line 
    `mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /run -o remount,size=85M`
to extends at startup.*(The 85M is for my conf.)*