# How folders created in /var/run on each reboot

Tags: boot, filesystem

In recent ubuntus (specifically, what interests me the most is 12.04) `/var/run` is tmpfs, and thus I assume it starts empty with each reboot.

Yet, I see there some folders, like `/var/run/mysqld` and numerous others. How those folders created on each reboot? Is there some template folder which copied to `/var/run/` (and if so, which script does that), or each folder `mkdir`'ed separately, or what ?

EDIT:
Please, do not answer that `/var/run` is persistent, or that `/run` is persistent. Because it is NOT.

Even if it is so on *your* system, it is not so on a regular 12.04.

Comment: Hmm, so I'm going to have 50 rep. wasted on one of the two answers which are both  obviously plainly wrong....

Comment: Someone, please answer ANYTHING sensible and you get +50 rep :)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

(Thanks to @Zulakis and [an answer on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/824394/391930) for pointing out that this answer had not kept up with Ubuntu's ongoing development.)

With the adoption of `systemd` as of [15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613366/rationale-for-switching-from-upstart-to-systemd), there is now a centralized mechanism for the creation of temporary files and directories such as these. A service wishing to use this method can remove `mkdir` commands in its own startup script and instead place a `.conf` file in `/etc/tmpfiles.d`, `/run/tmpfiles.d`, or `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d`, with Ubuntu services seeming to prefer the last option. For example, my system now has:

```
$ egrep -r /var/run /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d

/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:L /var/run - - - - ../run
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sudo.conf:d /var/run/sudo 0711 root root
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sudo.conf:D /var/run/sudo/ts 0700 root root
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/postgresql.conf:d /var/run/postgresql 2775 postgres postgres - -
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/sshd.conf:d /var/run/sshd 0755 root root
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/screen-cleanup.conf:d /var/run/screen 0775 root utmp
```

The `d` means to create a directory if it doesn't already exist, after that is the path, and the rest are the permissions, user, and group. These directories will be created regardless of whether the corresponding service is ever started.

For full documentation, see [`man tmpfiles.d`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/tmpfiles.d.5.html).

---

**OLD PRE-SYSTEMD ANSWER:**

Looks like they're created dynamically by individual services as they start:

```
$ sudo egrep -r 'mkdir.*/var/run' /etc

/etc/init.d/ssh:        mkdir /var/run/sshd
/etc/init.d/bind9:      mkdir -p /var/run/named
/etc/init.d/timidity:    mkdir -p /var/run/timidity
/etc/init.d/bzflag:                mkdir -p /var/run/bzflag
/etc/init.d/dns-clean:mkdir /var/run/pppconfig >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
/etc/init/winbind.conf: mkdir -p /var/run/samba/winbindd_privileged
/etc/init/dbus.conf:    mkdir -p /var/run/dbus
/etc/init/ssh.conf:    mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/sshd
/etc/init/libvirt-bin.conf:     mkdir -p /var/run/libvirt
/etc/init/cups.conf:    mkdir -p /var/run/cups/certs
```

I believe this is the one that handles mysqld:

```
[ -d /var/run/mysqld ] || install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld
/lib/init/apparmor-profile-load usr.sbin.mysqld
```

`man install` says that the -d form will "create all components of the specified directories".

Comment: This does not always seem to be the case: https://serverfault.com/questions/824393/var-run-directory-creation-even-though-service-is-disabled

Comment: Thanks, @Zulakis. I made some edits and would appreciate knowing whether they're correct based on your experience with this feature.

Comment: Looks good to me! Thanks for updating your answer :)

Comment: Upvote for the egrep -r command. Been looking for a search within file search! :-)

Comment: When defining through unit files services that need to create files in a private folder inside `/var/run`, you have a cleaner way of creating the private folder instead of *tmpfiles.d* by means of the *RuntimeDirectory* declaration in the unit file. Please check  <https://serverfault.com/questions/779634/create-a-directory-under-var-run-at-boot> for further details

Answer (score 5):

The new tmpfs-mounted `/run` folder allows programs like udev, lvm and mdadm to keep runtime data from initrd until shutdown.

`/var` is a standard directory of any Linux/UNIX system - it stands for "variable" and is a place where a lot of logs, cahces, BUT also program variable settings files and even some system configuration databases reside.

Most things in `/var` should be properly purged and regulated by the system.  Your swap files for virtual memory also live in `/var` so don't mess with that. `/var/run` also holds a lot status and parameter information of actively running process daemans.

This directory contains system information data describing the system since it was booted. Files under this directory must be cleared (removed or truncated as appropriate) at the beginning of the boot process. Programs may have a sub-directory of `/var/run`; this is encouraged for programs that use more than one run-time file.

Well since `/var/run` is mounted as tmpfs. That means it's totally empty when your machine boots and it's meant to be like this to prevent stuff like daemons not starting because of a left-over PID-file.

**Startup scripts** usually create the directories they need before using them. If you want to store a PID-file either put it in `/var/run` directly or create a directory before creating the PID-file. This is no place to store data that needs to remain there across reboots.

<sup>Sources:Pathname & Linux System Administrator's Guide</sup>

Answer (score 5):

For anyone that comes across this thread because you're looking for a solution to how you can configure an application so that it creates the directory in `/var/run` so it can store it's sock or pid file or whatever… here's an example.  I came across this thread because I wanted to store the MySQL sock file in `/var/run/mysqld`.  So, after I came across this thread, I started looking in the `/etc/init` files for examples.  dbus was a good one.  And, I came up with this mysql startup configuration:

```
start on runlevel [2345] 
stop on runlevel [!2345] 
expect daemon 

pre-start script 
    mkdir -p -m0755 /var/run/mysqld 
    chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld 
end script 

exec /etc/init.d/mysql start 
pre-stop exec /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

The pre-start script part did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

> Yet, I see there some folders, like /var/run/mysqld and numerous
>   others. How those folders created on each reboot ? Is there some
>   template folder which copied to /var/run/ (and if so, which script
>   does that), or each folder mkdired separately, or what ?

As defined in the [File Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) the `/var/run` or `/run` is used to store volatile runtime data.

All the folders and files created in there are managed by the respective program that created the files. There is no such a thing as a template folder that is copied, every program can use that folder to store volatile information. The stored data gets lost when the system reboots.

A common thing for using the `/run` folder is to store the `pid` of running daemons, marker files that contain the process number of a process. They are mainly used for the start/stop scripts that you can find for example in `/etc/init.d/`

I hope that made things clear to you!

br

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is not absolutely correct. The location of the `/var` folder is negotiable - that is, you can use an alternate partition or volume on which to locate the `/var` folder. Regardless of where the `/var` folder is located, the `/var/run` folder is a symlink to the `/run` folder and its contents remain after reboots, though many of the files in `/run` are generated or modified at boot by services starting during boot. So it is the services - such as `mysqld` - that call for loading files into the `/var/run` directory and are set up to create subdirectories if they do not exist currently.

Comment: I created some folders in /var/run and they disappeared after reboot. (specifically on 12.04)

Comment: Also see here that /var/run is indeed tmpfs http://askubuntu.com/questions/57297/why-has-var-run-been-migrated-to-run

Answer (score -3):

douggro is absolutely right, /var/run is mounted as tmpfs, and /var/run is a symlink to /run which is persistent across reboots, so anything that goes in /run will also appear in (and stay in) /var/run.

So any boot services like mysqld, which is a daemon which is started at boot time, that create files in /run, will also have files visible in /var/run (symlink to /run remember). If you want to create a file that will persist through a reboot in /var/run, create it in /run and then reboot.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: You're both mistaken, or using non-standard setups. Check for yourself. mount | grep /run  .... tmpfs on /run type tmpfs

Comment: "If you want to create a file that will persist through a reboot in /var/run, create it in /run and then reboot." That is NOT correct. `tmpfs` is volatile and changes are lost.