# Ubuntu 16.04 Screen lock suddenly not working

Tags: unity, 16.04, lock-screen

I have two notebooks with Ubuntu 16.04.1/Unity 7.4.0 and few days ago the Lock screen stopped working on both machines. It worked before. The option to lock the screen has disappeared from the menu too. When I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, only black screen is shown, after mouse moving or any keyboard pressing desktop is back without prompting password.

When I use `dm-tool lock` from terminal, it shows the Lock screen, but after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> I am back to the desktop (without being prompted for a password). I think this maybe started after some update.

I use Ubuntu on my working notebook and I must protect the machine when I leave it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows (I found solution in another question):

- Install "Unity Tweak Tool" with `sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool`
- I ran it from the Launcher and select System > Security > Enhance system security - **Enable** Desktop lock.

I don't know what disabled this option. but now it is working OK.

Comment: I was checked this checkbox suddenly(I mean it was checked) and when I read your answer, disabled it. Now I'm able to lock(just when it remain unchecked)!

Comment: Typing `Lock Screen` will show it on the launcher.

Answer (score 15):

## You don't need to install 3rd party package

You can [re-enable lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/992418/ubuntu-17-04-no-longer-asking-for-password-when-coming-out-of-sleep-mode/1000243#1000243) directly from the terminal.

To see if Lock screen is disabled:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
false
```

If result is `true` then use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

Comment: Wow! After two months I've finally found the right answer! @WinEunuuchs2Unix for president!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @WinEunuuchs2Unix, you should not need to install 3rd party software to resolve this issue. This issue recently happened to me after upgrading software on my work machine.

I first attempted

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```

which returned `false` so I knew that wasn't the issue. Next, I checked the `nopasswdlogin` line in `/etc/group` file and saw that my username was added to this. I removed my login name and saved the file. This solved my lock screen problem.

Here is a reference on how to read this file: [Understanding /etc/group File](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcgroup-file/)

Answer (score 1):

this solved my problem too; but now the clause has been changed in Unity Tweak Tool as shown below.
It now says: *ENHANCE SYSTEM SECURITY BY **DISABLING**:*

So, make sure that everything is unchecked.

### [image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04. The keyboard shortcut Super-L did not work. The fix was to (re)install the missing package gnome-screensaver:

```
sudo apt install gnome-screensaver
```

For the OP with Ubuntu 16.04, (s)he might accidently have lost this package.

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem also with Ubuntu 18.04. I could lock the screen with Super-L but could never unlock it again as I just had the black screen of death!

After hard powering the Laptop off/on, I entered

sudo apt install gnome-screensaver

Now it works perfectly again.