# upgraded to 15.04 init conf file doesn't work

Tags: 15.04, upstart, macbook, init

I've recently upgraded to 15.04. On 14.10 I had a conf file which would start a program on upstart. On 15.04 that doesn't work and the program won't start.

This is the .conf file:

```
# mbpfan - A simple daemon to control fan speed on all Macbook/Macbook Pros \
#   (probably all Apple computers) for Linux 3.x.x

description     "mbpfan"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
umask 022

console log

exec /usr/sbin/mbpfan -f
```

I install everything like with the following commands:

```
sudo cp mbpfan.upstart /etc/init/mbpfan.conf
sudo start mbpfan
```

Which gives me the error:

```
 start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket
 /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

Why doesn't this work and what changes do I need to make for it to start mbpfan on boot?

Answer (score 3):

The headline news this week is that **Ubuntu version 15.04 doesn't use upstart**.  It uses systemd.

You can go back to upstart, which is a question all to itself; or you can write a systemd *service unit* for your service; or you can swipe an already-written one.  There are plenty of already-written ones about.

[This `mbpfan.service` unit by Ismail Khatib](https://github.com/CeRiAl/Fan-Control-Daemon/blob/master/mbpfan.service) has been around since 2012, for example.  However, I recommend that you edit it to say

```
Type=simple
```

and

```
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mbpfan -f
```

`mbpfan`'s "daemonization" is entirely superfluous (under both upstart and systemd); is not functionally correct in any case; and under systemd will also result in unnecessary duplicated log information, as systemd already records the log information that `mbpfan` sends to its standard output.

## Further reading

- ["Boot and service management"](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes#Boot_and_service_management).  *Upstart version 15 release notes*.  2015-04-24.  Ubuntu.
- [systemd.exec](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- [systemd.service](http://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.

Comment: JDEBP is correct here that mbpfan demonization is not suitable for systems such as systemd. Development began under Slackware, so I decided to make mbpfan not tied up to any particular distribution/service manager. On the other hand, it is easy to make it work under all possible managers using small adjustements (e.g., the -f flag). Pull requests on the service files are very welcome. Also PR in general are very welcome :-)