# Nginx logrotate logs

Tags: server, nginx, logrotate

I am running Ubuntu 15.04 and have a standard installation of `nginx` (`apt-get install nginx`) running.

Everything is running fine but I notice that the `nginx` logs are being rotated but `nginx` carries on outputting to the same log file e.g. `/var/log/nginx/error.log` is empty yet `/var/log/nginx/error.log.1` is getting stuff written to it.

Of course if I restart `nginx` the regular log file starts to get written to. Is there a bug somewhere in the `logrotate` script? Does it need to restart `nginx` on a rotate ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## You are running Ubuntu version 15.

Yes, you could muck around with `logrotate` and with script snippets as in the other answers.  But *you are running Ubuntu version 15*.  On your operating system services are run under systemd, which *by default* captures their standard error and syslog outputs and handles the logging.  There's no need for nginx to be writing to that `error.log` file in the first place.  There's no need for `logrotate` *at all*.

Other answers and the comments beneath them may cause you to look at `/etc/init.d/nginx` perhaps.  Don't.  That file is irrelevant.  *You are running Ubuntu version 15*.  The relevant file, as provided right out of the box in the Ubuntu nginx-common package, is `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` which is what systemd will be using, completely ignoring the old `/etc/init.d/nginx` file which is entirely overridden by a proper systemd service unit file.

Other answers might lead you to look at `/etc/logrotate.d/nginx` as well.  You might be mystified by the contradiction between [what you can clearly see there](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/nginx.git/tree/debian/nginx-common.nginx.logrotate?id=39c9401f342fd82db34658e07370e61e4a854286), trying to run the old System 5 `rc` script with a non-standard `invoke-rc.d` subcommand, and the claim that there's no `postrotate` stanza.  But again, simply don't.  Don't focus on these logrotate control stanzas in the first place.  *You are running Ubuntu version 15* with a package that has a system unit already and isn't using System 5 `rc` scripts on your operating system, and a service manager that logs service output.

Two steps to doing things the systemd way:

## Configure nginx more appropriately.

Your `nginx` service needs to be told to simply write its log to its standard error.  As a bonus, you can send your access log to the journal via syslog, which systemd also intercepts.

This is done with [nginx global configuration directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html) and http module directives.  Specifically:

- `error_log stderr ;`
- `access_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log ;`

You either change your `nginx.conf` file to say these as [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29005073/340790) did, or do what Alexander Kuznecov [did here](https://github.com/akuznecov/PKGBUILD-nginx-custom/blob/master/nginx.service) and change your `nginx.service` unit file to pass (global) directives on the `nginx` command line:

```
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nginx -g 'daemon on; error_log stderr; master_process on;'
```

## Forget about `logrotate` entirely.

systemd puts the standard output and standard error of all services into its journal.  It handles the rotation of the journal files itself.  There are no signals and no nginx service reloading involved at all.  You can read the last few entries in the journal that are related to the service with (run as the superuser or as an `adm` user)

```
systemctl status nginx.service
```

You can read everything in the log from that service since the last boot with

```
journalctl -u nginx.service -b
```

Comment: definitely the right thing to do.. You have to be wary of things like fail2ban nginx filters and other things dependent on the log files.. But yep. Much better.

I have a problem though turning on access_log to stderr. With the example above using syslog:server=unix:/dev/log; I get:

``nginx: [emerg] open() "/usr/share/nginx/syslog:server=unix:/dev/log" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed``

Comment: Does this pertain to only Ubuntu 15 and higher, or did the change come with an earlier version?

Comment: See the operating system's own release notes, and the many items here on Ask Ubuntu such as http://askubuntu.com/questions/613366/ .

Comment: upvoted! any ideas for 18.04

Answer (score 2):

The reason `nginx` is writing to the rotated file is a missing `postrotate` section in the `logrotate` file for `nginx` to reload the configuration of `nginx`.

`logrotate` has renamed the file all right but renaming does not closes or changes the file descriptor (kernel internally maintains a descriptor table that demonstrates all open files by file handles or descriptors), the file handle remains the same as it was previously. So the `nginx` process will keep on dumping to the same file handle (the rotated one) rather than the newly created file.

To solve this issue, add a `postrotate` section in the `logrotate` configuration file to reload the configuration file of `nginx`.

For example, here is the `postrotate` section of `/etc/logrotate.d/apache2`:

```
    postrotate
            if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null ; then \
                /etc/init.d/apache2 reload > /dev/null; \
            fi;
    endscript
```

Comment: @Arronical I have not used `nginx` so i am not sure but the concept is generic..

Answer (score 1):

Create a file /etc/logrotate.d/nginx with the following content. Works on debian at least. Your mileage may vary

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 99
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 0640 www-data adm
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /bin/kill -USR1 `cat /run/nginx.pid 2>/dev/null` 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```