# What is new on ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: 15.04

I noticed that Ubuntu 15.04 was recently released. What is new over 14.04 and 14.10 ?

Comment: "recently"? 2 months ago is long in operating systems worlds :D

Comment: @downvoters, It's better to tell the OP reason of downvoting. Here my +1 to equalize

Comment: If you ask a question that boils down to _What's in the release notes?_ you'll get two groups of people: the "teach a man to fish" crowd who tell you to read the release notes for yourself, and the "give a man a fish" crowd who try to read the release notes to you and almost always miss or gloss over bits. One far better question in this vein, which boiled down to _I've read the release notes for myself; now what is this particular bit all about?_, was already asked at the time of the release: http://askubuntu.com/questions/613366/ I suggest reading the release notes and asking another one.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search returns this - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes#New_features_in_15.04

Answer (score 1):

There are not a lot of visible changes in 15.04 and it was a rather dull release. For any release there is a release note released. You can find that [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes).

Besides the usual updates of software versions (new kernel, new firefox etc) the only big difference is that we started using [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd).

Answer (score 0):

It removes init.d and replaces it with systemd, has the linux kernel 3.19, and a lot of bug fixes, other then that it doesn't really seem like much, It's mostly updated packages.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ubuntu 15.04 – New Features

- Systemd
- Unity 7.3
- Compiz 0.9.12
- Ubuntu Linux Kernel 3.19
- Application Updates
- New Default Wallpaper
- Ubuntu Make
- Local menu is back as default

The details can be found in [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/04/ubuntu-15-04-download-new-features), Also [this](http://www.itworld.com/article/2906313/whats-new-in-ubuntu-15-04.html) would be helpful