# Why when I run' sudo apt-get remove upstart' does ubuntu try and remove ubuntu-desktop, unity, and unity-greeter?

Tags: unity, upstart

I'm having problems with Xorg randomly crashing on Ubuntu 15.10. I checked `~/.xsession-errors` and there's some stuff in there about upstart, so I'm trying to delete it from my system. I read that since Ubuntu 15.04 upstart has been replaced with systemd, so not sure why it's still there (upstart processes are running now). A while ago I accidentally deleted some upstart config files so perhaps that's why.

Anyway I ran `sudo apt-get remove upstart`, and then it said:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED
  ubuntu-desktop unity unity-greeter upstart
```

So I didn't continue. Why is ubuntu trying to remove the desktop and unity  as well when I just want to remove upstart?

Comment: unity-greeter depends on upstart, so if you removed only upstart, unity-greeter would have unmet dependencies, that's why your package manager intends to remove this package as well.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. How does unity greeter work then for newer versions of ubuntu that use systemd not upstart? Or has upstart been retained in these new versions for certain functions?

Comment: Does this mean unity and unity-desktop depend on upstart too? But then how is it that ubuntu's supposedly switched from upstart to systemd?

Comment: unity and ubuntu-desktop depend on unity-greeter. A useful application to figure out what package depends on which is *aptitude*, it has a graphical user interface (in the terminal). I don't know anything about upstart or systemd, so I can't say what was the idea to make these packages depend on upstart. I just know some things about package management and I came across your question, that's why I posted my comment.

Answer (score 1):

> I read that since Ubuntu 15.04 upstart has been replaced with systemd

You read wrong.  As explained in the last bullet point of https://askubuntu.com/a/613814/43344 , upstart is still used for so-called *"user" init*.  If you uninstall it, all of the things in your desktop that try to talk to a per-session/per-user service manager (as opposed to the system-wide one) will stop working.  Hence the package dependencies.

### Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194208/5132

Comment: Ah thanks. Do you know what would be the best way to reinstall upstart without uninstalling unity desktop? Or should I reinstall them all from command line mode?