# Super confused between upstart and systemd

Tags: 15.10, shutdown, desktop-environments, upstart, systemd

Given I'm running 15.10 my system should be using `systemd` confirmed by...

```
$ ps -p1 | grep systemd && echo systemd || echo upstart
    1 ?        00:00:02 systemd
systemd
```

But I have an `upstart` script defined, `~/.config/upstart/startup.conf`

```
description "my startup scripts"
start on desktop-start

task
console log
script
  exec ~/scripts/startup.sh start
end script
```

The startup script works I guess using `upstart`?

But then I have a shutdown script also defined, `~/.config/upstart/shutdown.conf`

```
description "my shutdown scripts"
start on desktop-end

task
console log
script
  exec ~/scripts/backup.sh start
end script
```

But that script does not start.  And when I try to start either manually..

`sudo start startup` or `sudo start shutdown` I get..

```
start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
```

The shutdown script works if I run it manually from `~/scripts/backup.sh`.

Permissions

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 deanresin deanresin    933 May 28 01:31 backup.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 deanresin deanresin   2061 May 28 14:06 startup.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deanresin deanresin 124 May 28 14:04 shutdown.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deanresin deanresin 218 May 28 14:02 startup.conf
```

thanks to commenter below it was a permission issue.  Changed to..

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 deanresin deanresin 124 May 28 14:04 shutdown.conf
-rwxrwxr-x 1 deanresin deanresin 218 May 28 14:02 startup.conf
```

Edit:  for some reason `startup.conf` doesn't require execution permissions.  These permissions were working...

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 deanresin deanresin 124 May 28 14:04 shutdown.conf
-rw-rw---- 1 deanresin deanresin 218 May 28 14:02 startup.conf
```

**Why is my startup script working and why isn't my shutdown script working?**  And why is upstart working?  Or is it?  I'm super confused.

Comment: You mentioned `~/.config/upstart/startup.conf` for the startup script but `~/.config/shutdown.conf` (no `upstart/` in the path) for shutdown. Is that a typo?

Comment: Ok. Please update the question by posting the exact permissions of those two `.conf` files **and** of the two `.sh` files.

Comment: I will shortly but I double checked the permissions already.

Comment: Yeah it turned out to be a permission issue as you suspected.  I had to make the shutdown.conf executable.  Oddly the startup.conf wasn't but still worked or I did something I don't remember.  I'm still confused why upstart is working at all.  I like it though.. it is more intuitive than systemd from initial ignorant impressions.

Comment: I guess I should turn that into an answer then. If you instead want to answer yourself, **do not** update the question. Write a self-answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely a permissions issue. Both `.conf` files need to be executable.

Do:

```
chmod a+x ~/.config/upstart/shutdown.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

> And why is upstart working? Or is it? […] I'm still confused why upstart is working at all.

systemd is running as the system-wide service manager.  upstart is running as a per-session service manager.

### Further reading

- https://askubuntu.com/a/613814/43344
- ["Boot and service management"](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/VividVervet/ReleaseNotes#Boot_and_service_management).  *Upstart version 15 release notes*.  2015-04-24.  Ubuntu.
- ["Session Init"](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#session-init). *upstart Cookbook*. Ubuntu.
- James Hunt, Stéphane Graber, Dmitrijs Ledkovs, and Steve Langasek (2012-11-12). ["Respawning user jobs and PID tracking"](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/Specs/RaringUpstartUserSessions#Respawning_user_jobs_and_PID_tracking).  *Ubuntu Raring upstart user sessions*.  Ubuntu.
- Nathan Willis (2013-04-17).  [*Upstart for user sessions*](http://lwn.net/Articles/547422/).  LWN.
- [*Discuss how Session Inits (upstart) could be migrated to systemd*](http://summit.ubuntu.com/uds-1403/meeting/22155/core-1403-session-init-systemd-migration/)
  2014-03-11.  Ubuntu summit.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194208/5132